# Can't fix non-normality and heteroskedasticity

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption

I am attempting, via linear regression, to model a dataset.I've tried various transformations on the response/ and predictors, as well as WLS but the assumptions are not met. I'm looking for the possible existence of significance in variables, so from my understanding the normality of the residuals is needed to perform the requisite significance tests. There doesn't appear to be any multicollinearity issues.
The response is a continuous variable that measure the total amount element T (arbitrary label) in soil, and the predictors are the plots of land where the soil is, weather data such as precipitation in inches, temperature etc, and the amount of treatment injected into the soil. The data is collected over ~50 months, each row of the dataset is the average monthly value of the predictors, and there are ~10 plots of land (so ~50 rows per plot of land).  Please find below, images of the qqplot and the residual vs. fitted plot.
The clustering of data in the residuals vs. fitted plot suggest to me that maybe another predictor is uncaptured driving the deviation from the assumptions but I am not 100% sure. Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

[image]
[image]

PS: There are outliers in this dataset, so that may be an issue but there is no reason to suspect that they are a result of data misentry. Hope this explanation is clear, will answer any questions in the comments. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you estimated by pooled OLS? This almost certainly calls for fixed/random effects.

Comment: Thank you for swift response @PhilipHartfield. No I have not estimated by pooled OLS, unfamiliar but will do some research on this method. Curious, why do you suspect the use of random effects? The client is only interested in these specific plots of land not generalizing to a larger population so calling on my memory fixed effects seemed like the straightforward solution. Can you offer a further explanation?

Comment: Normality of the errors is not necessary for inference, nor is homoskedasticity (unless you are thinking about finite sample inference, in which case you can make any suitable parametric assumption, not just normality)

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty this is an inference on a finite sample, so I believe the assumptions of normality and homoscedasticity are pretty strong. When you mention using any suitable parametric assumption, is there any guide to choosing an appropriate parametric distribution to model (as per the clients words I believe there is no literature surrounding modelling this kind of problem in his field)?

Comment: @PhilipHartfield gotcha! Even if I incorporate random effects, with this setup the random slopes and intercepts are significant (also slope^2), but the fixed effects are still required to have residuals that are normally distributed and homoscedastic. The homoscedasticity can be relaxed a bit as none of the residual variances are greater than 4 times of another, but I don't think mixed effect models are very robust to normality deviance (p-value <2e-16 shapiro wilks test). What can be done in this case? Can I just not make an inferential conclusions? Thanks again for you're recommendations.